# Crystal Reports Custom Sort

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I have a hierarchy in my database that goes as follows:

1

1.1

1.1.1

1.1.2

1.2

1.3

...

1.10

When I ask for Crystal Reports to sort it, the following occurs:

1

1.1

1.1.1

1.1.2

1.10

1.10.1

1.11

1.2

I need my report to be ordered the way I first labeled it. Is there any way for me to get the correct sorting order?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For this you need group by `Hierarchy` and apply custom sorting in `group options` in crystal reports.